# Storing values in sessionStorage in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, session-storage, sessionstorage

I have stored all the values in state called data as below:

```
loadValues = () => {
    this.setState({
      data: [`{"Price:" "${this.state.price}","Title": "${this.state.title}","MenuId": "${this.state.code}","Quantity": "${this.state.counter}"}`],
    })
  }
```

Now i need help in storing these values in sessionStorage and print it in console.(reactJs). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do like the following:

```
loadValues = () => {
  this.setState({
    data: [`{"Price:" "${this.state.price}","Title": "${this.state.title}","MenuId": "${this.state.code}","Quantity": "${this.state.counter}"}`],
  }, () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('data', this.state.data)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

u can use sessionStorage.setItem() to store values
and sessionStorage.getItem() to get values

Answer (score 3):

It's not a question about reactJs. It's just javascript.
use this

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```